# Latex code questions for curly C

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

[image]

What is the latex code for the curly C? (on the second line of the picture)

Comment: There is actually a [TeX stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: btw, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is useful for finding specific TeX symbols (although it didn't work for me for this one.)

Answer (score 5):

With `\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}`, `\mathscr{C}` will produce the curly C you want. Without this package, it still produces something similar: $\mathscr{C}$